# Supressing the 'Remove Duplicates' alert

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

I'm attempting to remove duplicates from a list in Excel with a macro. The problem is that Excel prompts me with the "Remove Duplicates" alert to select which columns have headers. I need to avoid this alert so that the macro does not need human intervention. Here is what I'm using now:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A200000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
```

Any help or suggestions you can provide are much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think setting `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` should suppress them.

Comment: I'm using that but it still prompts me. I actually use the following:     `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`
`Application.EnableEvents = False`
`Application.ScreenUpdating = False`

Comment: "I'm using that but it still prompts me" - how about including that rather important piece of information in the body of your question? ;-)

Comment: Have you tried adding column headers?

Comment: Testing on Windows. Wondering if it is an issue with MacOS and/or Excel for Mac 16.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with macOS or the version of Excel for Mac (16.10). I confirmed that this does work with Windows 10.

Comment: Is there a solution for macOS? `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` does not work as noted above.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this work around for Mac](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/remove-duplicates.html) posted by [Jim Gordon](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/profile/75a2b744-a259-49bb-8eb1-7db61dae9e78) on a Microsoft forum